# Как узнать номер объекта в массиве которого коснулся через OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: unity3d

У меня на игроке есть скрипт с массивом объектов. На каждом есть Box Collider 2d с включенным триггером.

Вопрос. Если игрок дотронется до блока и сработает OnTriggerEnter2D по тегу Border, как узнать какой это объект из массива ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция OnTriggerEnter имеет аргумент - ссылку на объект, с которым произошло касание. Вы можете просто найти в массиве индекс этого элемента:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider2D other) {
    GameObject obj = other.gameObject;
    array.FindIndex(0, array.Count - 1, el => el == obj); // Что-то LINQ-овское
    // ИЛИ
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        if (array[i] == obj)
            // НАЙДЕНО
}
```

Answer (score 0):

collider.gameobject.name ?
по имени в массиве найдите

Comment: Но ведь имена на сцене могут быть одинаковыми?